# How to mute an audio stream

Tags: iphone, audio

Is there way to mute an audio stream or at least control the volume?

cheers

Comment: How are you playing the audio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the Audio Queue Services, this is how you adjust the volume:

```
AudioQueueRef queue = [self yourAQCreationMethod];
OSStatus rc = AudioQueueSetParameter(queue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, 0);
if (rc) {
  NSLog(@"AudioQueueSetParameter returned %d when setting the volume.\n", rc);
}
```